# Proving identity of probabilties

Tags: probability

> Let A,B,C be events. Prove that: $P(A^c \cap(B\cup C))=P(B)+P(C)-P(C \cap A)-P(B \cap C)-P(A \cap B)+P(A\cap B \cap C)$ and find similar expression for $P(A\cup (B^c \cap C))$

I tried proving it by starting from the right side (The following steps will be based on that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$):

$$ \begin{align*}
&P(B)+P(C)-P(C \cap A)-P(B \cap C)-P(A \cap B)+P(A\cap B \cap C)\\
&=P(B\cup C)-[P(A \cap C)+P(A \cap B)-P((B \cap A) \cap(C \cap A))]\\
&=P(B\cap C)-P((A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C))\\
&=P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap(B\cup C))\\
&=P(B\cap C)-[P(A)+P(B\cup C)-P(A\cup(B\cup C))]\\
&=-P(A)+P(A \cup B\cup C)\\
&=P(A^c)-1+P(A)+P(B)-P(B\cup C)\\
&=P(B)-P(B\cup C)
\end{align*} $$
Am I wrong? I'd be glad to get a hint.

Comment: Venn diagrams would help since you are dealing with 3 sets.

Comment: Add $P(A)$ to both sides and use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: It is not correct, $A$ disappeared yet $\Pr(A)$ is relevant. As a matter of general strategy, if you cannot think of anything very clever, go in the expansion direction: uglification is easier than prettification. So for mechanical, rewrite left as $(A^c\cap B)\cup (A^c \cap C)$. Write $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$ as $\Pr(B) -\Pr(A\cap B)$, same with the other one, and you are not far from the end.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I tried but somehow I'm stuck proving $-P(B \cap C)+P(A \cap B \cap C)=-P(A^c\cap(B\cap C))$. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:
$$\begin{align*}
&P(B)+P(C)-P(C \cap A)-P(B \cap C)-P(A \cap B)+P(A\cap B \cap C)\\
&=\cdots\\
&=-P(A)+P(A \cup (B\cup C)) \qquad \text{(this is your fifth equality)}\\
&=-P(A)+[P(A)+P(B\cup C)-P(A\cap(B\cup C))]\\
&=P(B\cup C)-P(A\cap(B\cup C))\\
&=P([A\cup A^c]\cap[B\cup C])-P(A\cap(B\cup C))\\
&=P([A\cap(B\cup C)] \cup [A^c\cap(B\cup C)] )-P(A\cap(B\cup C))\\
&=P(A\cap(B\cup C)) +P(A^c\cap(B\cup C))-P(A\cap(B\cup C))\qquad \text{(since they are disjoint)}\\
&=P(A^c\cap(B\cup C))
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $A^c\cap (B\cup C)=(A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c\cap C)$. But 
$$\Pr((A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c\cap C)) =\Pr(A^c\cap B)+\Pr(A^c \cap C)-\Pr(A^c\cap B\cap C).$$

Replace $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$ by $\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$, and $\Pr(A^c\cap C)$ by $\Pr(C)-\Pr(A\cap C)$,

Replace $\Pr(A^c\cap B\cap C)$ by $\Pr(B\cap C)-\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$, and it's over.

Comment: where did the compliment disappear in the last replacement?

Comment: It is the same type of replacement as the other two. $\Pr(A^c\cap X)=\Pr(X)-\Pr(A\cap X)$. In the third replacement $X=B\cap C$. You can think of it as coming from the more natural $\Pr(A^x \cap X)+\Pr(A\cap X)=\Pr(X)$.